# Create package of pgn-extract

Tags: dpkg

I want to create a package for installation of the latest version of [pgn-extract](https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/djb/pgn-extract/). I downloaded `pgn-extract.tgz` and decompressed the archive.
But I can't think any further myself, because I have no experiences in the concept of building packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way (for some value of “easiest”) of going about this is to download the existing [`pgn-extract` package](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/pgn-extract) and use that as a base:

1. download the current source:

   ```
   wget ftp://ftp.cs.kent.ac.uk/pub/djb/pgn-extract/pgn-extract.tgz
   ```
2. extract it:

   ```
   tar xf pgn-extract.tgz
   ```
3. determine the version number:

   ```
   grep Version pgn-extract/index.html
   ```

   (I get “17-38”, so I’ll use that in the following instructions; if you’ve got a later version, replace “17” and “38” as appropriate)
4. link the tarball to the “.orig” tarball that the Debian build tools will expect:

   ```
   ln -s pgn-extract.tgz pgn-extract_17.38.orig.tar.gz
   ```
5. download the source package and extract it:

   ```
   apt-get source pgn-extract
   ```
6. copy the existing `debian` directory into your `pgn-extract` source directory:

   ```
   cd pgn-extract
   cp -a ../pgn-extract-17.21/debian .
   ```
7. add a changelog entry for your version, something like

   ```
   dch -v 17.38-0.1 "New upstream release."
   ```
8. build the new package; if errors occur here, fix the packaging as appropriate, and try again:

   ```
   dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
   ```

In my case, I had to fix `makefile.patch`; this showed up as an error patching the code at the start of the build:

```
dpkg-source: info: using source format '3.0 (quilt)'
dpkg-source: info: building pgn-extract using existing ./pgn-extract_17.38.orig.tar.gz
patching file Makefile
Hunk #1 FAILED at 37.
Hunk #2 succeeded at 48 (offset 1 line).
1 out of 2 hunks FAILED
dpkg-source: info: the patch has fuzz which is not allowed, or is malformed
dpkg-source: info: if patch 'makefile.patch' is correctly applied by quilt, use 'quilt refresh' to update it
dpkg-source: error: LC_ALL=C patch -t -F 0 -N -p1 -u -V never -E -b -B .pc/makefile.patch/ --reject-file=- < pgn-extract.orig.ltAFev/debian/patches/makefile.patch gave error exit status 1
dpkg-buildpackage: error: dpkg-source -b pgn-extract gave error exit status 2
```

To fix this, I proceeded as follows:

1. force-apply the patch:

   ```
   export QUILT_PATCHES="debian/patches"
   quilt push -f
   ```
2. check out the rejects in `Makefile.rej` and apply them manually using an editor; with the current version of `pgn-extract`, that means:

   1. look for the line `# AIX 3.2 Users might like these alternatives`
   2. find the line just above that saying `CC=gcc`
   3. above that, delete the line saying `-O3`, and replace the `\` at the end of the previous line with `$(CPPFLAGS)`, so the whole line ends up as

      ```
             -I/usr/local/lib/ansi-include -std=c99 $(CPPFLAGS)
      ```
3. refresh the patch:

   ```
   quilt refresh
   ```
4. run the build again.

You could also start from the extracted Debian source package and use `uscan` to download and process the latest tarball, but I’ll let you investigate that if you’re interested.